# PHP Proxy as middleware

Tags: php, javascript, cors

I have created a proxy page for calling xml from javascript client. I have placed

```
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');
 header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
 header('Pragma: no-cache');
 //header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: false');
 $header[] = "Content-type: text/xml";
```

But when I m calling though jquery or any other framework it is still showing me access origin issue. PHP file i have placed in different domain.

How to I can solve this problem?

Comment: Are you accessing a server in a different domain? jQuery won't allow AJAX calls to a domain other than the one it is in.

Comment: AlexW - Are you sure $.ajax does't work with CORS?

Comment: Have you tried using a .htaccess to allow cross-domain transfers? http://jacksonkr.com/content/enable-cross-domain-policy-files-using-htaccess

Comment: ajax not wor with cross-domain. only AJAX level 2 - but it in developments state

Comment: I m developing an app for mobile browsers, webkit supported. i m using jquery and ajax is not working. yes I have also try .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

Are you cached? Clear it and try again.

If it is showing the php file in the other domain and the CORS page is not redirecting, it should have no problems as long as the browser supports it.